# How do I set the name attribute on a multiselect listbox generated using LIstBoxFor and MultiSelectList in Asp.net MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Here is how I'm currently calling the helper in my view (using Razor and C#):

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Measures, new MultiSelectList(Model.Measures, "MsId"), 
new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "measureId" } })
```

This works fine setting the "id" in the form element but when I try and do something like this:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Measures, new MultiSelectList(Model.Measures, "MsId"), 
new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "measureId" }, { "name", "measureId" } })
```

The source code generated is still:

```
<select id="measureId" multiple="multiple" name="Measures">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name is generated from the `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>` parameter passed. The name of the property passed is used so in your case `m => m.Measures` the name `Measures` is used.  This is to enable model binding to work when your form is posted to an action.

You can change the name value by change the property name to MeasuresId or if that's not possible you can use the [non typed version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.listbox.aspx)

```
@Html.ListBox("measureId", new MultiSelectList(Model.Measures, "MsId"));
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to figure out where that was getting set to begin with. Your explanation was perfect and now I understand why I got it wrong, not just how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

pass in:

```
new { name= "yourname"}
```

for your html attributes in the overload of ListBoxFor

Comment: I've tried that. I'm sort of doing that already when I'm defining that Dictionary object in the second code snippet.

Comment: the format you specified wasn't the same though : ) try it as I posted and see if it works - its the consistent format to use for htmlattributes, no need to define a dictionary as you did inline.

Comment: I actually needed to have a manual `id` but leave the model bound `name`, and a regular `ListBox` does not let you override the `id` or the `name`, however the ListBoxFor does...

Comment: The model bound name IS the id